# Preventing 4NF relations

Tags: sql, normalization, database-normalization

I have been going through database normalization concepts and came across a doubt regarding fourth normal form.

Consider below table :

```
movie_id  | actor_id | producer_id
-----------------------------------

1         | 1        | 1

1         | 2        | 1

1         | 2        | 2
```

Primary key for above relation is : movie_id,actor_id,producer_id as A single movie can have multiple actors and multiple producers.

So, above table is in BCNF.

As per the terminology of 4NF, we should eliminate the multivalued dependencies from the above table to reach 4NF, getting 2 tables as a result.

```
movie_actor
movie_id  | actorId
---------------------

movie_producer
movie_id  | producer_id
------------------------
```

The above tables are in 4NF.
However,
I don't understand why this table encountered this multivalued dependency as such things can be handled by "First normal form" itself.

The 1 NF tells us that, we should avoid repeating groups. So, as a movie can have multiple actors, we should have separated the actors in its separate movie_actor table in order to satisfy 1 NF.

Can any one tell me if my understanding is correct ?
PS. the above example is taken from book : Relational database design and implementation : Jan Harrington, 3rd edition, Page no. 117

Comment: Isn't `movie_producer` redundant here? `producer_id` might be put directly to the `movie` table

Comment: "I don't understand why this table encountered this multivalued dependency" --- because you expected that `producer_id` may vary for the same `(movie_id, actor_id)` tuple, which is not.

Comment: The fact that a movie might have multiple actors doesn't imply that the actors were stored as a repeating group.

Comment: @zerkms *producer_id might be put directly to the movie table* No. A movie can have multiple producers. So, we should not add duplicate data for each movie in MOVIE table if it has > 1 producer.

Comment: @Shinchan: oh, that's my fault then. For some reason I thought it's strictly 1:1

Comment: @zerkms *because you expected that producer_id may vary for the same (movie_id, actor_id) tuple, which is not* I mean to say that this dependency should have been handled by 1NF. I have the very first table which the book says that it's in BCNF. I wondered how does it come so far. Why that multivalued dependency was not removed while satisfying 1NF?

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' *The fact that a movie might have multiple actors doesn't imply that the actors were stored as a repeating group*   Can you please elaborate this? I didn't get why this should not be considered as repeating group ? Thanks.

Comment: Your definitions & reasoning are wrong. "So, above table is in BCNF." & "we should eliminate the multivalued dependencies" & "we should have separated the actors" are not sound conclusions. Explain each "so" & the "because" in detail since your (unsound) reasoning is not obvious. You're going to have to use definitions of 1NF, BCNF & 4NF for that, so quote them from your textbook, also your definition for the terms they use. Eg you misuse "repeating group": "A repeating group is an attribute that has more than one value in each
row of a table." There are none.

Comment: Unfortunately that is a poor textbook. Eg PKs are irrelevant but it uses them. It ignores trivial FDs. Its treatment of 2NF is nonsense. It defines 3NF wrongly. All I can suggest is that to do your assignment you show how each step of your work follows the book. But that book isn't going to teach you normalization.